# basic angular routing not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am still a beginner at Angular and my problem is with angular routing, under no way I can bring up the ng-view. For test purposes all files are inside the same folder and the controller is included in the admin.module.js

```
 **Index.html**     
            <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html ng-app="myApp">
                <link rel="stylesheet" src="/css/style.css">
                    <script src="/libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
                    <script src="/libs/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
                    <script src="admin.module.js"></script>
                    </script>
                <body>
                <div ng-view></div>
                </body>

  **admin.module.js**

            (function () {
            "use strict";

            var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

            app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider
                    .when('/test', {
                        templateUrl: 'test.html',
                        controller: 'AppCtrl'
                    })
                    .otherwise({
                        redirectTo: '/'
                    });
            });

            app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope) {
                $scope.message = 'hello from the other side';
            });
        }());

    **test.html**

        <h1>{{message}}</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
```

A link to [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uKKBJSabVjibYbWb66HU?p=linter).

I do not have any console errors and all files load up.

Comment: since you don't have any console errors, does the screen show a blank page?

Comment: yes and when i add test to the URL from my understanding it should display the message i have in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found 3 errors in your plunker:

1. You have used angular 2 with angular 1 syntax
2. There was redirectTo: '/' but you have only /test route
3. There was no ng-app directive

Please see fixed plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Nki3Djk4adihx31HABUi?p=preview

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/test', {
                templateUrl: 'test.html',
                controller: 'AppCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/test'
            });
    });

    app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'hello from the other side';
    });
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
  </body>

</html>
```